# TransactionScopeOption qual a diferença entre as opções?

Tags: c#, transações

Eu estava fazendo uma pesquisa sobre as opções para [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) e encontrei as seguintes configurações:

**Required** 
Uma transação é necessária para o escopo. Se já existir, ele usa uma transação de ambiente. Caso contrário, ele cria uma nova transação antes de inserir o escopo. Esse é o valor padrão.

**RequiresNew** 
Uma nova transação é sempre criada para o escopo.

**Suppress** 
O contexto de transação de ambiente será suprimido ao criar o escopo. Todas as operações dentro do escopo são realizadas sem um contexto de transação de ambiente.

Em que contexto cada um melhor se aplica?

Se a opção `Suppress` faz com que as operações dentro do escope não sejam realizadas em uma transação, então pra que declarar uma transação? Qual a utilidade dessa opção?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Começando pela sua pergunta final, `Suppress`, por si só, não tem grande utilidade:

```
using(TransactionScope ambiente = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(TransactionScope suprimida = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))        
    {
        // erros aqui não cancelam a transação `ambiente` 
    }
}
```

Ou seja, uma única transacção suprimida dentro de uma outra transacção fará com que erros dentro da transacção suprimida não abortem a transacção ambiente (considera-se que uma transacção é ambiente quando é a raiz, ou a primeira, de todas as transacções de uma ligação), o que significa que a transacção ambiente é completada com sucesso.

No entanto, considere o seguinte caso:

```
using(TransactionScope ambiente = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(TransactionScope requer = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))        
    {
        // erros aqui CANCELAM a transacção `ambiente` 
    }

    using(TransactionScope suprimida = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))        
    {
        // erros aqui NÃO cancelam a transacção `ambiente` 
    }
}
```

Neste caso, considere que tem dois pedaços distintos de código, um vital para a sua aplicação (e.g, salvar os dados de um cliente) e um outro pedaço de código não vital (escrever um *log* para a base dados).

No caso demonstrado, mesmo que a escrita do *log* falhe, os dados do cliente estão salvaguardados porque o código responsável por os salvar encontra-se dentro de uma transacção associada à transacção `ambiente` e ambas serão completadas no fim do bloco `ambiente`.

Por sua vez, a escrita dos *logs*, ainda que dentro do bloco `ambiente`, está dentro de um bloco cuja transacção foi suprimida, o que significa, que caso falhe, os erros não iram provocar um retrocesso da transacção `ambiente`.

Por fim, a terceira opção, `RequireNew` indica que, mesmo que exista uma transacção ambiente, o código dentro do seu bloco deve ser completado e guardado independentemente da transacção ambiente.

```
using(TransactionScope ambiente = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(TransactionScope requer = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))        
    {
        // erros aqui CANCELAM a transacção `ambiente` 
    }

    using(TransactionScope requerNova = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))        
    {
        // erros aqui NÃO CANCELAM a transacção `ambiente` 
        // mas CANCELAM a transacção `requerNova` 
    }

    using(TransactionScope suprimida = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))        
    {
        // erros aqui NÃO cancelam a transacção `ambiente` 
    }
}
```

(resposta baseada [neste artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx#Y1642))

Comment: Sua resposta é perfeita @Omni , muito obrigado! Só um pequeno detalhe para o bloco `requerNova`, no exemplo dado acabou ficando como `Required` ao invés de `RequiresNew`.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues obrigado pela correção :)  malvado do *copy-paste*

Answer (score 5):

No [artigo sobre Transações do Israel Aéce](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2199/wcf-transacoes.aspx), diz:

> Se o método suportar transação e ela estiver criada, automaticamente,
>   qualquer recurso transacional que você acesse dentro desta operação,
>   automaticamente será alistado (*auto-enlistment*) e, com isso, toda e
>   qualquer manipulação será gerenciada pela transação. Isso quer dizer
>   que não há necessidade de escrevermos código para criar a transação,
>   pois o [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms730266(v=vs.110).aspx) já garante isso; independentemente da transação criada
>   pelo WCF, você pode perfeitamente, dentro do método, criar um bloco
>   transacional através da classe `TransactionScope`, que um dos seus
>   construtores aceita uma das opções especificadas no enumerador
>   `TransactionScopeOption`, que permite "interagir" com o ambiente
>   transacionado existente. Os possíveis valores são:
>
> - **`Required`**: Uma transação é requerida. Caso a transação exista, o processo fará parte dela; do contrário, uma nova transação será
>     criada.
> - **`RequiredNew`**: Uma nova transação é requerida. Independentemente se existe ou não uma transação, sempre será criada
>     uma nova.
> - **`Suppress`**: Não é necessário uma transação. Independentemente se existe ou não uma transação, a tarefa não será envolvida em um
>     ambiente transacionado.

Se o escopo é instanciado com `Required` uma transação de ambiente estiver presente, o escopo une a transação. Se, por outro lado, não há nenhuma transação de ambiente, o escopo cria uma nova transação e se tornar o escopo raiz. Este é o valor padrão. Quando `Required` é usado, o código dentro do escopo não precisa ter um comportamento diferente seja a raiz ou apenas associando a transação de ambiente. Ele deve operar identicamente em ambos os casos.

Se o escopo é instanciado com `RequiresNew`, é sempre o escopo raiz. Ele inicia uma nova transação, e sua transação se torna a nova transação ambiente dentro do escopo.

Se o escopo é instanciado com `Suppress`, ele nunca faz parte de uma transação, independentemente de se uma transação de ambiente está presente. Um escopo instanciado com esse valor sempre ter `null` como sua transação de ambiente.

As opções acima são resumidas na [tabela](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx#Y1642):

```
 TransactionScopeOption |   Transação de ambiente   |    Escopo faz parte
------------------------|---------------------------|------------------------------
    Required            |           Não             |   Nova transação (será a raiz)
    Requires New        |           Não             |   Nova transação (será a raiz)
    Suppress            |           Não             |   Nenhuma transação
    Required            |           Sim             |   Transação de ambiente
    Requires New        |           Sim             |   Nova transação (será a raiz)
    Suppress            |           Sim             |   Nenhuma transação
```

É interessante saber quando usar  `Required` ou `RequiresNew`, nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629361/5327226) do stackoverflow em inglês mostra isso. Traduzi para deixar a resposta mais completa.

Para saber quando usar `Required` ou `RequiresNew`, tomando com base o exemplo, depende do que você quer que aconteça se outro método chama `ProcessRequest` dentro de outra operação:

```
public void SomeOtherMethod() {
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TrasansctionScope()) {
        // Another DB action
        ProcessRequest();
        // Yet another DB action
    }
}
```

Se você quiser o `ProcessRequest` para utilizar a operação criada pelo `SomeOtherMethod`, use `TransactionScope.Required`. Este é o padrão (e ainda cria uma transação quando você chama ele sem ter criado um outro escopo da transação até a pilha de chamadas). Se quiser forçar esse método para usar sempre sua própria transação (novo), use `TransactionScope.RequiresNew`.

Referências:

- [Transações](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2199/wcf-transacoes.aspx)
- [TransactionScopeOption Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: `Se você quer ProcessRequest para utilizar a operação criado pela SomeOtherMethod, use TransactionScope.Required` e `Se você quer que ele para forçar esse método para usar sempre sua própria transação (novo)..` Essa explicação ficou confusa. @taisbevalle

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, melhorei.